# Dart: issue with where() function for filtering list

Tags: filter, dart

I am having an issue to filter a list based on a predicate. I have a list of string called _expenses where I am trying to filter out the expenses which belong to certain "Categories".  But IDE gives me error in the boolean predicate saying "Avoid using unnecessary statement". Also during compilation it gives another error saying "flutter: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null". What am I doing wrong?

```
 this._expenses.where((Expense e) {
      e.category != 'Deposit' ||  e.category != 'Loan (Inward)/Debt' || e.category != 'Loan(Outward) Settlement';
    }).toList().forEach((Expense e){
      totalExpense += e.amount;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda used as `where` argument don't return anything (a `return` is missing).

```
this._expenses.where((Expense e) {
      return e.category != 'Deposit' ||  e.category != 'Loan (Inward)/Debt' || e.category != 'Loan(Outward) Settlement';
    }).toList().forEach((Expense e){
      totalExpense += e.amount;
    });
```

Comment: thanks so much. also an alternative is to use a fat arrow => and exclude both the return and curly braces.